# list folders where Codeigniter searches for classes

Tags: php, codeigniter

Codeigniter does not find trivial classes:

`Unable to load the requested class: Bcrypt`

But the same goes for custom made classes defined in files in `application/libraries/`. I am used that django lists the folders where it searched for a file, but did not find one. Obviously CI must also iterate over some list of folders or files, but is not as polite to display them along with the error.

It seems as if CI has a naming convention to deduce the (set of) filename(s) where it would expect a class to be. How can I programmatically `error_log` the list of folders or filenames that Codeigniter or PHP tried to track down this class?

*EDIT:* The lines of code that produce such a loading-error are:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','mi_file_fetcher');
```

in `application/config/autoload.php` and

```
$this->load->library("bcrypt");
```

in `application/models/User.php`

As stated in the comments, I was not asking for a fix, I was asking for a list.

Comment: Where is Bcrypt.php located and how did you try to load it?

Comment: How have you tried to load custom classes located in `application/libraries/`?

Comment: Obviously I want to resolve the error, but that was not at all my question. I want to get the list of files or folders that CI inspected before it decided it didn't find the class. I think this information is more valuable in resolving problems and understanding how CI loads classes than endless explanations on how you should name your classes in what files. Especially now that I have reverse engineered that part in `Loader.php`, the source code is actually significantly more insightful than what I could find in the documentation about loading from the `libraries`-folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do so by updating `system/core/Loader.php`

```php5
protected function _ci_load_library_files_tried($class, $subdir, $params, $object_name)
{
    $files_tried = array(BASEPATH . 'libraries/' . $subdir . $class . '.php');

    foreach ($this->_ci_library_paths as $path) {
        if ($path === BASEPATH) {
            continue;
        }

        array_push($files_tried, $path . 'libraries/' . $subdir . $class . '.php');
    }
    return $files_tried;
}

protected function _ci_load_library($class, $params = NULL, $object_name = NULL)
{
// ... 

    // If we got this far we were unable to find the requested class.
    $files_tried = $this->_ci_load_library_files_tried($class, $subdir, $params, $object_name);

    log_message('error', 'Unable to load the requested class: '.$class .
        ", tried these files:\n" . join("\n", $files_tried));
    show_error('Unable to load the requested class: '.$class .
        ', tried these files:<ul><li>' . join('</li><li>', $files_tried) . '</li></ul>');
}
```

Would be great if CI actually provided decent debugging information.

Comment: It is an exceptionally bad idea to hack the core files. I recommend you read the documentation on [Extending Core Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html#extending-core-class)

Comment: It definitely is, I was reverse engineering a CI-project, which was completely rewritten in Python 3 and Django for maintainability and readability. However, it stays unfortunate that CI would not provide (1) a stack trace of where it was trying to load this model and (2) list the files it tried. This helped me a lot of figuring out where it was looking. It turned out it it tried `/var/www/folder_name/application/Bcrypt/Bcrypt.php` and `/var/www/folder_name/system/Bcrypt/Bcrypt.php`. The `Bcrypt` folder was not what I expected from the CI documentation.

Answer (score -1):

The CodeIgniter (CI) documentation does tell you the default locations of libraries, models, helpers, views and many other framework objects. There isn't a section that explicitly lists the folders though. The [Loader Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html) documentation does tell you, but you have to dig for it a bit.

The subtopics on the [General Topics](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/index.html) section of the docs clearly state the default locations for the various classes the frameworks uses and where to put custom classes.

In most cases following the prescribed file structure and using the loader class, e.g. (`Bcrypt.php` is in `/application/libraries/`)

```
$this->load->library('bcrypt');
```

works perfectly.

There are cases (none of which seem to be involved in your problem) where CI needs help. Rather than hack or extend `CI_Loader` an autoloader is useful in these cases.

There are lots of ways to add an autoloader but my preference is to use CI's [Hooks](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html) feature. Here's how.

In **config.php** set 'enable_hooks' to TRUE

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

These lines go in **/application/config/hooks.php**

```
$hook['pre_system'][] = array(
  'class' => '',
  'function' => 'register_autoloader',
  'filename' => 'Auto_load.php',
  'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

The following is the contents of **/application/hooks/Auto_load.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

function register_autoloader()
{
  spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');
}

/**
 * Allows classes that do not start with CI_ and that are 
 * stored in these subdirectories of `APPPATH` 
 * (default APPPATH = "application/" and is defined in "index.php")
 *     libraries, 
 *     models, 
 *     core
 *     controllers
 * to be instantiated when needed.
 * @param string $class Class name to check for
 * @return void
 */
function my_autoloader($class)
{
  if(strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
  {
    if(file_exists($file = APPPATH.'libraries/'.$class.'.php'))
    {
      require_once $file;
    }
    elseif(file_exists($file = APPPATH.'models/'.$class.'.php'))
    {
      require_once $file;
    }
    elseif(file_exists($file = APPPATH.'core/'.$class.'.php'))
    {
      require_once $file;
    }
    elseif(file_exists($file = APPPATH.'controllers/'.$class.'.php'))
    {
      require_once $file;
    }
  }
}
```

The function `log_message($level, $message)` could be used in the above if you wanted.

If you are using some other creative folder structure you will have to modify the above to accommodate that layout.

Comment: Strangely enough, `Loader.php` tried `application/libraries/`**Bcrypt**`/Bcrypt.php, which does not seem to match with the CI-documentation I read on libraries. Oh well ...

Comment: PS: `my_autoloader` changes the autoloader behavior, I just want to debug a problem.